# VelocityJS Scrolling errors within relative containers

Tags: jquery, css-position, css-transforms, velocity.js

Velocity is working in part of my project, but the issue I'm experiencing is reproducible in JSFiddle (link below), and I think it may somehow be related to Issue #770 on the project's GitHub page.

*(Note: I had links to this and other articles below, but don't have the reputation to post more than 2 links, so my apologies for having to look these up.)*

I would like to know if anyone can:

- Verify that this is a known bug,
- See a fix for this issue,
- Find an error in my implementation, or
- Offer an alternative resolution.

I'm building a website implementing an off-screen push menu in which the entire content is wrapped in a relative DIV that pushes to the right using CSS transforms to reveal the menu. There are a couple levels of relatively positioned DIVs that emulate fixed positioning of my site header (which is, by necessity, wrapped in the push menu DIV).

The push menu is adapted from a **Codrops Playground** article *(search "multi level push menu" on Tympanus.net)*. There is a demo linked from the article. There is also a link to notes on the faux fixed positioning of elements in combination with CSS transforms within the article (halfway down).

The menu on my development site works as expected. I implement Velocity from some of the menu items to scroll down to internal page sections, which also works fine (scrolling from the top of the page).

*However*, I would also like to use Velocity scrolling within the page from a fixed-position sidebar at the top, to allow users to click a section title to auto-scroll to that section. *Unfortunately, the sidebar links only work if the page is scrolled to the very top.* From any other scroll position, the links don't function correctly.

*If the page is scrolled down, clicking any link only scrolls the page further down, even if the section requested within the click event is above the current scroll position.*

The behavior can best be seen in this Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Josefism/j4dLhssc/

**Basic Site Structure**

```
<div class="site-container">
  <div class="menu-pusher">
    <div class="scroller">
      <div class="scroller-inner">
        <div class="site-inner">
          <div class="content-sidebar-wrap">
            <main class="content">
              <article class="page">
                <div class="entry-content">
                  <div id="section-1" class="section-1">
                    <p>Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum.</p>    
                    <p>Cupim aliqua culpa bacon.</p>    
                    <p>Aliqua irure qui chicken.</p>
                  </div><!-- End Section 1 -->

                  <div id="section-2" class="section-2">
                    <p>Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum.</p>    
                    <p>Cupim aliqua culpa bacon.</p>    
                    <p>Aliqua irure qui chicken.</p>
                  </div><!-- End Section 2 -->

                  <div id="section-3" class="section-3">
                    <p>Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum.</p>    
                    <p>Cupim aliqua culpa bacon.</p>    
                    <p>Aliqua irure qui chicken.</p>
                  </div><!-- End Section 3 -->

                  <div id="section-4" class="section-4">
                    <p>Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum.</p>    
                    <p>Cupim aliqua culpa bacon.</p>    
                    <p>Aliqua irure qui chicken.</p>
                  </div><!-- End Section 4 -->

                </div><!-- End Entry Content -->
              </article>
            </main>
            <aside class="sidebar">
              <section class="widget">
                <div class="widget-wrap">
                  <div class="text-widget">
                    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                      <li class="section-1-link">Section 1</li>
                      <li class="section-2-link">Section 2</li>
                      <li class="section-3-link">Section 3</li>
                      <li class="section-4-link">Section 4</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div><!-- End Text Widget -->
                </div><!-- End Widget Wrap -->
              </section>
            </aside>
          </div><!-- End Content Sidebar Wrap -->
        </div><!-- End Site Inner -->
      </div><!-- End Scroller Inner -->
    </div><!-- End Scroller -->
  </div><!-- End Menu Pusher -->
</div><!-- End Site Container -->
```

**CSS** (modified only to accommodate JSFiddle reproduction of the issue)

```
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.site-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 90px;
}

.menu-pusher {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.scroller {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 400px;
}

.scroller-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.site-inner {
  position: relative;
}

main {
  display: block;
}

.content {
  float: right;
}

.content-sidebar-wrap .content {
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
}

.sidebar .widget {
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: #FFF;
}

.sidebar-menu {
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar-menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 1%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar-menu li:hover,
.sidebar-menu li.hovered {
  color: green;
}

.page {
  display: block;
}

.section-1 {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 20px 20px 100px 20px;
}

.section-2 {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  padding: 20px 20px 100px 20px;
}

.section-3 {
  background-color: #AAA;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 20px 20px 100px 20px;
}

.section-4 {
  background-color: #555;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 20px 20px 100px 20px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

**jQuery Velocity Implementation** (Does not include my Velocity implementations from menu items, as those already work.)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  // Add Velocity scrolling to the internal section sidebar links
  $(".section-1-link").on("click", function() {
    $("#section-1").velocity("stop", true).velocity("scroll", {
      container: $(".scroller"),
      duration: 1000,
      easing: "easeInOutSine",
      delay: 300,
      offset: 1
    });
  });
  $(".section-2-link").on("click", function() {
    $("#section-2").velocity("stop", true).velocity("scroll", {
      container: $(".scroller"),
      duration: 1000,
      easing: "easeInOutSine",
      delay: 300,
      offset: 1
    });
  });
  $(".section-3-link").on("click", function() {
    $("#section-3").velocity("stop", true).velocity("scroll", {
      container: $(".scroller"),
      duration: 1000,
      easing: "easeInOutSine",
      delay: 300,
      offset: 1
    });
  });
  $(".section-4-link").on("click", function() {
    $("#section-4").velocity("stop", true).velocity("scroll", {
      container: $(".scroller"),
      duration: 1000,
      easing: "easeInOutSine",
      delay: 300,
      offset: 1
    });
  });

  // Callback to section menu in primary sidebar to indicate scroll position
  $(".scroller").on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollerTop = $(".scroller").scrollTop();
    var section1TopDist = $("#section-1").offset().top;
    var section2TopDist = $("#section-2").offset().top;
    var section3TopDist = $("#section-3").offset().top;
    var section4TopDist = $("#section-4").offset().top;
    if (section4TopDist < 90) {
      $(".section-2-link, .section-3-link, .section-1-link").removeClass("hovered");
      $(".section-4-link").addClass("hovered");
    } else if (section3TopDist < 90) {
      $(".section-2-link, .section-1-link, .section-4-link").removeClass("hovered");
      $(".section-3-link").addClass("hovered");
    } else if (section2TopDist < 90) {
      $(".section-1-link, .section-3-link, .section-4-link").removeClass("hovered");
      $(".section-2-link").addClass("hovered");
    } else if (section1TopDist < 90) {
      $(".section-2-link, .section-3-link, .section-4-link").removeClass("hovered");
      $(".section-1-link").addClass("hovered");
    } else {
      $(".section-1-link, .section-2-link, .section-3-link, .section-4-link").removeClass("hovered");
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a bit of testing and troubleshooting I figured out what was causing my problem. In case anyone else using Velocity.js experiences a similar issue with scrolling inside a containing element, I'm posting my solution here as a troubleshooting reference.

The problem, as noted in the annotations in the code block below, was that the "scrollPositionCurrent" was being added to the new scroll position and throwing off the returned total. Removing that from the calculations did the trick for me, and now scrolling within a containing element works as expected.

I have since used my modified Velocity.js file in other sites to scroll the entire page with no containing element, and that still works correctly as well.

The code block below comes from lines 3171-3205 of the current version of Velocity.js on GitHub as of a few days ago (mid-October 2017).

The original code is still present in the snippet for reference but has been commented out.

```
/* Scroll also uniquely takes an optional "container" option, which indicates the parent element that should be scrolled --
as opposed to the browser window itself. This is useful for scrolling toward an element that's inside an overflowing parent element. */
if (opts.container) {
    /* Ensure that either a jQuery object or a raw DOM element was passed in. */
    if (Type.isWrapped(opts.container) || Type.isNode(opts.container)) {
        console.log("GOT IT!");
        /* Extract the raw DOM element from the jQuery wrapper. */
        opts.container = opts.container[0] || opts.container;
        /* Note: Unlike other properties in Velocity, the browser's scroll position is never cached since it so frequently changes
         (due to the user's natural interaction with the page). */
        scrollPositionCurrent = opts.container["scroll" + scrollDirection]; /* GET */

        /* $.position() values are relative to the container's currently viewable area (without taking into account the container's true dimensions
         -- say, for example, if the container was not overflowing). Thus, the scroll end value is the sum of the child element's position *and*
         the scroll container's current scroll position. */
        /* scrollPositionEnd = (scrollPositionCurrent + $(element).position()[scrollDirection.toLowerCase()]) + scrollOffset; */ /* GET */
        /* CORRECTION - Applied by Josef Cook 
           Scroll position of element within a containing element was incorrect. Adding current scroll position blows out the total. 
           Had to remove current scroll position addition (commented out above) to make this work correctly. */
        scrollPositionEnd = ($(element).position()[scrollDirection.toLowerCase()]) + scrollOffset;
        /* If a value other than a jQuery object or a raw DOM element was passed in, default to null so that this option is ignored. */
    } else {
        opts.container = null;
    }
} else {
    /* If the window itself is being scrolled -- not a containing element -- perform a live scroll position lookup using
     the appropriate cached property names (which differ based on browser type). */
    scrollPositionCurrent = Velocity.State.scrollAnchor[Velocity.State["scrollProperty" + scrollDirection]]; /* GET */
    /* When scrolling the browser window, cache the alternate axis's current value since window.scrollTo() doesn't let us change only one value at a time. */
    scrollPositionCurrentAlternate = Velocity.State.scrollAnchor[Velocity.State["scrollProperty" + (scrollDirection === "Left" ? "Top" : "Left")]]; /* GET */

    /* Unlike $.position(), $.offset() values are relative to the browser window's true dimensions -- not merely its currently viewable area --
     and therefore end values do not need to be compounded onto current values. */
    scrollPositionEnd = $(element).offset()[scrollDirection.toLowerCase()] + scrollOffset; /* GET */
}
```